# Basic Input/Output in Python

Tags: python

I am using notepad++ to write code for python and have a variable that I need to add 1 to for my next question.  I am new to coding and would like to know how to achieve this.  I would also like to phrase the question so that the answer (variable plus 1) is placed between text.  Below, in my next line I would like it to read (for instance if the number is 3) How often do the 4 of you visit?

I have tried different ways of framing my variable +1 within parentheses and quotation marks but at best, when run, it shows exactly what I wrote not the answer to the equation.

`famnumber = input ("How many of your family members still live there?")`

I would like the answer to appear within text as noted above if possible.
Here is some code:

```
famadd = float(famnumber) + (1)
print ("Do all (famadd) of you get together often?")
```

Comment: Show the code that you've tried. Likely though, you wrote `var + 1` instead of `var += 1`. You need to reassign the result back to a variable using `=`

Comment: and tell us how you "run" this code.

Comment: In what way is notepad++ actually relevant to your problem? Please, as a new user here, first take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, check out the formatting options when you [edit] your question, it makes it easier to understand what you're doing. Lastly, Python's `input()` function changed significantly between versions 2 and 3.

Comment: famadd = float(famnumber) + (1)
print  ("Do all (famadd) of you get together often?")                                              So I got the variable to add one.  However, in the second line how do I get the answer to the equation to appear in the midst of the text?  Thank you.

Comment: @Brock - Please do not write lumps of unformatted and, hence, difficult to read code in comments. Instead please [edit] the question to add that code in a neatly formatted way together with an explanation of what it does and why it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Note that when you you get something from input, it's a string. So using `famnumber += 1` won't work, as you can't add a number to a string. So we have to turn the numeral string into an actual number. You can use `int()` to convert the input text into an integer. Then to include the value in a new string for your next question, use `%d` ('d' for 'digit').  This makes more sense than using a float, since people don't report family members in fractions of whole numbers (likewise, you don't want to say something like 'How often do the 4.0 of your meet?').

```
famnumber = input("How many of your family members still live there? ")
new_number = int(famnumber) + 1
next_question = input("How often do the %d of you meet? " % new_number)
```

Other ways to accomplish the same thing is converting 'famnumber' itself from a string to an integer, then back into a string to join in the sentence.  Personally I'd go with the previous method, but this should give you an idea of some of the other things you can do in Python:

```
famnumber = input("How many of your family members still live there? ")
famnumber = int(famnumber)
famnumber += 1
next_question = input("How often do the " + str(famnumber) + " of you meet? ")
```

Also, while Notepad++ is a great text editor, if you're planning on doing a lot of Python scripting and writing, you may want to consider instead using an IDE, such as PyCharm, or IDLE which is included in the Python package.  Tools like this make it easier for yourself to read and run your code.

Comment: Bill M.  Thank you so much.  That worked great and I appreciate it!  Frustration relieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this kind of code:

```
famnumber = input("How many of your family members still live there?")
incremented_number = int(famnumber) + 1
next_number = input("How often do you " + str(incremented_number) + "visit")
print(next_number)
```

In the second line simply cast the input to `int` and increment it by one.

In the third line put the variable where you want it to be shown surrounded by `+` signs. You have to cast it to a string by using `str()` because the return type itself is a string. You can verify the type of the variable `next_number` simply by adding this line `print(type(next_number))`